# Python class inheritance with Elasticsearch server connection

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, inheritance

I'm trying to create a python class that inherits the Elasticsearch class and builds upon it with some custom methods. The issue i am facing is that i'd like the class constructor to connect to the server, so initialisation is simple. Usually to connect to the server it looks something like this:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'XXXXXXX', 'port': XXXX}]
```

In my class, that i'm calling "Elastic", i'd like to connect to the server and return the Elasticsearch object upon initialisation of the class, i.e.:

`es = Elastic()`

which I can then use to perform existing Elasticsearch class methods, and my own custom operations, e.g.:

```
es.search() # existing class method
es.custom_method_example1() # new class method
```

I've been trying and failing to come up with a way to do this - my most recent attempt involved using the `__new__` dunder method so that I could return the connected `es` object as the new class:

```
class Elastic(Elasticsearch):
    def __new__(cls, timeout=10, max_retries=5, retry_on_timeout=True, *args, **kwargs):
        "Connect to our ES server."
        return Elasticsearch([{'host': 'XXXXX', 'port': XXXX}], timeout=10, max_retries=5, retry_on_timeout=True, *args, **kwargs)
    
    def custom_method_example1(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Performs some custom method that wasn't possible with the standalone Elasticsearch class
        """
```

Firstly it doesn't work:
`AttributeError: 'Elasticsearch' object has no attribute 'custom_method_example1'`, seems that it's no longer inheriting but replacing the class?

And secondly, I gather from reading about that `__new__` generally doesn't have much use (particularly for amateur programmers like me) so I'm probably taking the wrong approach / overcomplicating it here. If anyone knows the "right" way to do this it would be much appreciated - I've been reading a bit about factory design and it seems like the right way to go in general but im still making sense of it all (i'm an analyst by trade). I figure decorators might come into use somewhere??

Thanks and sorry for the waffle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed I was very much overcomplicating it. Didn't consider that class inheritance involves inheritance of the constructor itself - therefore I can call the subclass `Elastic` just as I was for the parent `Elasticsearch`:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

class Elastic(Elasticsearch):
    
    def custom_method_example1(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Performs some custom method that wasn't possible with the standalone Elasticsearch class
        """
```

To initialise the class and call it's methods:

```
es = Elastic([{'host': 'XXXXX', 'port': XXXX}], timeout=10, max_retries=5, retry_on_timeout=True)

es.custom_method_example1()
```

EDIT: I still had the issue of wanting to set new default parameters for my subclass constructor - I've now found out how to do this using `super()` which explicitly calls the parents constructor passing on arguments i set in the subclass constructor, leaving me with:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

class Elastic(Elasticsearch):
    def __init__(self, hosts=[{'host':'XXXXXX', 'port':XXX}], timeout=10, max_retries=5, retry_on_timeout=True):
        super().__init__(hosts=hosts,timeout=timeout,max_retries=max_retries,retry_on_timeout=retry_on_timeout)  

    def custom_method_example1(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Performs some custom method that wasn't possible with the standalone Elasticsearch class
        """
```

allowing me to initialise the class like so:

```
es = Elastic()
```